# Explain the usage of CloudBlob.BeginStartCopy

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

With the new asynchronous programming models that are being accepted into most C# libraries, I am starting to see many uses of the words **Begin** and **Start**, but these new wordings confuse me.

Take for example the method CloudBlob.BeginStartCopy

The docs say that it Begins an asynchronous operation to start a blob copy. Okay, so that makes sense in English, but I don't see where there are callbacks or something similar for when these operations End or Stop respectively...

Can someone send light on the meanings of these methods and how I monitor them for completion?

Comment: `ICancellableAsyncResult BeginStartCopy (Uri source, AsyncCallback callback, object state)` has an [`AsyncCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter

Comment: If your question is about the general async-await programming model, then the convention of Begin with callback is not followed. Or if your question is related to the method CloudBlob.BeginStartCopy then, it actually takes a callback. Check the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.beginstartcopy?view=azure-dotnet) here

Comment: So really the difference is, if I want a Callback then I use Begin. Begin means start doing something and tell me about it when it's done. Start means, go do something and I don't much care what happens, I'll move on and you finish that! This seems logical!